# how to secure s3 files with trusted signed users using cloudfront aws-sign?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, multer-s3

I need to secure my files which should not get directly played or downloaded in the browzer after copy pasting the link in the browzer.

Below is my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    aws = require('aws-sdk'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    multer = require('multer'),
    multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

var cfUtil = require('aws-cloudfront-sign');
/**************************/
var cfPk =
'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n' +
'MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAgBmGbFU3bxnZpqMQ2LwmFP4lq7RauurKCF623Snm1XGNQuF9\n' +
'XqDeK3TH3ZfYC6P4iQ+C+Ynw15UP/MGbULO2UCmLfkA30FyI/u46jdhdD7hvMqEj\n' +
'UOEBxVJGFhqrZyerd9A7dRqYS6DTbaz3Vb+aGNcBLuqPP9/TydkkqoFqQnft43W7\n' +
'mWPp7Cx+TDkY/untwF3TWJdiAeke3FBAB2mni+BlmrNQs3vfufhW2XMV8sSOY+cN\n' +
'7chQmruV1stS+KCGiFfkiel824KI/1yVUe7+ofDGJF7v1G6WD4XV2sBAz01EIWSK\n' +
'vo1txA1lSoRcFHmnNOB4d8dKncilxEjstq6J5QIDAQABAoIBAC/m26CJIUiXdw9c\n' +
'LQGPIgJ5oyaZM9kdfkskflfsddsdfldfksdfjlksdfkfdfdfjsdljdfsdfksd08G\n' +
'znfj3zT6UcmuhsdfkhsdkjfksdfkjsdfkjskjdfkjlszDfhkSJDFHksdjJj7U/TQ\n' +
'WFEla/9b7yJjhgdfjsdfkDfklDfkldkljfksjdhfkshdjsdfhksdfkjsdYqOIrnp\n' +
'67CzIc/U76qkT/hsgdfsdfklkghfksdfkhkdhfkdkksdhfklsdhfklskkGuZOBOn\n' +
'vbRyFdfsDfwajhflsdhfpoaSudfhahfhhgTA0yVFFkYOZ6z6xyqoT8Qs+eUVGXCP\n' +
'Au5h6WECgYEA/fjlmzHgMnyfsCugmd/Qbh4tyDVBET6jKKG/JI/K43DjTTLWthcx\n' +
'Rlse1B6LbvbdzvbzdghdfghdtrytyrtyrtyreTO7WQLAEtTUOngsXms33ZdHtzIj\n' +
'r6UW9yqiDG6wNHH3Ql8oJCMaKs8z/mrcPJut0JORLmqd68NeOyxeIi0CgYEAgR9a\n' +
'TG2L06zJZ2Zk6sFee/4nZ5HgMHavxt25/JJtLG4Rew/lb1N10QcSk3v4I7bl41uB\n' +
'QhlHfyYd1yb0a2iTckfdsdfsdfaDfAFAVx95NS0ti3tO1hsuPKVTrMTEpEB2lul3\n' +
'BQuZehOE9HCW2QlDnwBeM2SDA0kagknIh63XsZkCgYBgEkIQxfowPvJNOwOikYaP\n' +
'0TyySmrVsiMYIK9kjjxKcw6Yyk1sTjOk9FkWYP3SwHqfEs0L4hSn6u3F9/34bp+N\n' +
'fmtkUTW0WK3G0jtYV5XiegCEvZnelmxe9g1M7ESmfUyMWjwVUFen69tfLEhXymaL\n' +
'SryidN/rdgtM/vdrXOoy9QKBgAks4izGKAZ9o74uP4OTBBTJhaFNc2HePTVjciDp\n' +
'gsqCc8mL4qDbjGazGvXR/FsFVyalzPaddcweu0kaziZdm36Z1JPI4o1fMUijtVax\n' +
'voXJvfjVtWGgAbgj05NayZohX/14B9YG8fwDwRHhokZ/6wc0bn02ajzkh/a0KYTC\n' +
'rK4ZAoGAGqYbrwHYFFgAOhOaPdER9jK+MXWl1pUhdFTUbNETgF0Nay06GifY+1DA\n' +
'oTu2hg3k7z5464WANk/ixn5nlyRD/i8Ab4ENA56sFly9qOyEdWlXKNrocMd4wjJr\n' +
'ZVF3wvEieF2E1PTySKYNb0ZUm70nfzMj6sRFw9ow58LdpPVXIew=\n' +
'-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
/************************/


aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: 'mysecretaccesss',
    accessKeyId: 'myaccessKeyId'
});

var app = express(),
    s3 = new aws.S3();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'my_buket',
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            // console.log(file);
           // console.log(req);
            var newFileName = Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname;
            var fullPath = '/'+ newFileName;
            console.log(fullPath)


var cfKeypairId = 'HKASHDDAKSHDHSDKAJ';
var cfURL = 'http://smbhdshdb.cloudfront.net'+fullPath;
var signedUrl = cfUtil.getSignedUrl(cfURL, {
  keypairId: cfKeypairId,
  expireTime: Date.now() + 60000,
  privateKeyString: cfPk
});

console.log(signedUrl);

// console.log(req);
            cb(null, fullPath); //use Date.now() for unique file keys

        }


    })
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


app.post('/upload', upload.any(), function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("Uploaded!");
});

app.listen(3001, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3001!');
});
```

Below is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
Hey! Lets try uploading to s3 directly :)

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="optional title"/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="file" name="upl"/>
        <!-- <input type="file" name="uplo"/> -->
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my bucket policy which is wrong with principal.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ESHJDAKSJFYU(SAMPLE ACCESS KEY)"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

can somebody tel me how to give the bucket policy and how to enable security to my files?
i need only the files should get streamed or downloaded only with the signed urls.

help please?

Answer (score 0):

> can somebody tel me how to give the bucket policy and how to enable
>   security to my files?

If you've (1) created your CloudFront Key Pairs for your trusted signers, (2) set **Restrict Bucket Access** to **Yes** in the **Origins** tab and (3) made sure your bucket policy does not allow `GetObject` access except for the *Origin Access Identity*, then your files are already secured using signed URLs (or cookies). You could try pasting the URL in your browser to see that it does not get downloaded.

Whenever a client needs to download your private file, it should use the `signedUrl` your app created.

See:

[Creating CloudFront Key Pairs for Your Trusted Signers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-trusted-signers.html#private-content-creating-cloudfront-key-pairs)

[Creating an Origin Access Identity and Adding it to Your Distribution Using the CloudFront Console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-creating-oai-console)

> And i need to know what is the value of 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' in the below variable.

It is just a random string that gets generated when you create your CloudFront distribution the first time. It becomes part of the *domain name*. For example: `d7ip55b96n1wwe.cloudfront.net`.